# React: redux persistence in local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying out persisting data to localstorage with Redux.  I just made an array of alphabet letter.  Whenever I click the element with the onclick listener, I see the console log statement with a random letter each time but the UI doesn't re-render as it would with a setState() call, until I refresh the page.   What am I missing here?

`src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import myApp from './reducers';

import {loadState, saveState} from './localStorage'


const persistedState = loadState();

const store = createStore(
    myApp,
    persistedState
);

store.subscribe(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
});

function render () {
    ReactDOM.render(<App store={store}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
}

render();
```

`src/app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { switchName } from './actions'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = this.props.store;
  }

  handleChangeName = () => {
    let array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"];
    const data = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    this.store.dispatch(switchName(data));
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <p className="ntro" onClick = {this.handleChangeName} >
          Letter:  {this.store.getState().name}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`src/localstorage.js`

```
export const loadState = () => {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if (serializedState === null) {
            console.log("serialzed state null")

            return undefined;
        }
        return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (err) {
        return undefined;
    }
};


export const saveState = (state) => {
    try {
        console.log(state)
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);

    } catch (err) {};
}
```

`src/reducers.js`

```
const initialState = {
    name: "nada"
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SWITCH_NAME":
            return Object.assign({}, state,{
                name: action.data
            })

        default:
            return state

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `App` component is not subscribing to the store and so it does not re-render when the store changes (i.e. it will only use the first `name` value returned from `store.getState()`

To fix you could use [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) to `connect` to the store instead of passing it as a prop.

`src/index.js`

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// ...

function render () {
    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App store={store}/></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
}
```

`src/app.js`

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// ...

class App extends Component {

  handleChangeName = () => {
    let array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"];
    const data = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    this.props.switchName(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <p className="ntro" onClick = {this.handleChangeName} >
          Letter:  {this.props.name}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// note that `store` is no longer used inside the `App` component

const mapState = state => ({ state.name });
const actions = { switchName };

export default connect(mapState, actions)(App);
```

Alternatively you can more add a `render()` call inside the `subscribe` callback in `src/index.js`

```
// ...

store.subscribe(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
    render();
});

function render () {
    ReactDOM.render(<App store={store}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
}

render();
```

although you might want to do something else with the `registerServiceWorker()` call.

---

*Side Note:* have you tried [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)?

Comment: Thanks!!! I did initially use `redux-persist` but I was watching a tutorial online ( https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage ) from Dan Abramov who didn't use the library so I tried that approach.

So the way I see is that I'm using `redux` library rather than `react-redux` ...is that bad practice?

Comment: Correct, you are just are using React and Redux but not React-Redux.  Using React-Redux is completely optional, but, in my opinion, you will find things a lot easier if you use it. Also, please remember to [upvote and/or accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that have helped you solve your problem.